# Deserializing a protobuf ByteArray in Java that was passed from C++ over JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, arrays, protocol-buffers

i have a protobuffer message, whose fields are filled with data. I am serializing this message in C++ first to a char* and then copying the contents of that char* to a jbyteArray. Then i return the jbyteArray to my java-class, where i want to deserialize it, so i can access the individual fields of the message/class. But i don't really know how.

This is my code so far:

```
public String IMEI(){

    GetDeviceInfo nativeDeviceInfo = new GetDeviceInfo();

    byte[] ret = nativeDeviceInfo.getDeviceData();

    CellPhoneDevice.Builder device = CellPhoneDevice.newBuilder();


    try {
        device.mergeFrom(ret);
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!device.hasImeiNumber())
        return "imei empty";
    long imei = device.getImeiNumber();


    String str = String.valueOf(imei);

//      String str = new String(ret);   //see if ByteArray is even filled

    return str;
}
```

i've checked if the byteArray does contain data (see commented out line) and it is filled, so i'm guessing i'm doing something wrong with parsing the byteArray.
I've searched a lot of websites/tutorials, but there wasn't much on deserializing byteArrays and if there was, i couldn't replicate it (method undefined and such stuff).

When i run this code, it executes without any errors, but the string that should contain the imei only contains "0" and the method returns the "imei empty"-string.

So, yes... could someone please tell me, what's the way to deserialize a byteArray?

Comment: `(new Long(imei)).toString();` <-- uh... What about `String.valueOf(imei)`?

Comment: You've shown code, but not said anything about what's going wrong. That looks like it should be okay... what are you seeing? (And if the IMEI is meant to be a number, why are you converting it to a string?)

Comment: Sorry, what's going wrong is, that the String does not contain the expected imei-number, but "0".
Also the "if(!device.hasImeiNumber())" shows, that it has no ImeiNumber set.

Comment: Make sure that the bytes you're seeing in Java are exactly the same bytes as were generated in C++. E.g. you can print out the bytes as a list of numbers at both ends and compare. Make sure that the length actually matches what the protobuf's `ByteSize()` method returns in C++. A common mistake is to try to use `strlen()` to measure the length; this does not work, because the data is binary, not a text string.

Comment: @KentonVarda: Oh god you'r right. i did just that. i used strlen on the array, which in my case is 26 but ByteSize actually returns 148...
Why didn't i notice this myself...
Thanks a lot, now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a Java array in native code and getting no data (0's) on the Java side, check to make sure you are making a call to Release-TYPE-ArrayElements().  Here is an example snippet:

```
if ((function & FUNCTION_04) > 0 ) {
    arrayB = (jbyteArray) (*env)->GetObjectField(env, jObjectOut, fidB);
    pArrayB = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, arrayB, 0);
    arrayBsize = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arrayB);
    for (x = 0; x < arrayBsize; x++) {
        pArrayB[x] = x;
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, arrayB, pArrayB, 0);
}
```

Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html